# How to solve routing roblem on React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to set routes for my application and i have problems at the beginning..

I would achieve that when user is not logged in, application should redirect him to '/signIn' page.
If user is logged in, application should take him into '/'

I don't understand it but my currentUser is null. So app should redirect me to signIn (condition) but it still goes to HomePage

Any hints?

Below is my code what i've been trying so far

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      currentUser: null,
    };
  }
  unsubscribeFromAuth = null;
  componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribeFromAuth = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      this.setState({ currentUser: user });
    });
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribeFromAuth();
  }
  render() {
    console.log('Current state:', this.state);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" render={() => <HomePage currentUser={this.state.currentUser} />} />
          <Route
            exact
            path="/signIn"
            render={() => (this.state.currentUser ? <Redirect to="/" /> : <SignInPage />)}
          />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add verification user in route home page not login page:

```
  class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      currentUser: null
    }
  }
  unsubscribeFromAuth = null
  componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribeFromAuth = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      this.setState({ currentUser: user })
    })
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribeFromAuth()
  }

  render() {
    const redirection = this.state.currentUser ? <Redirect to="/" /> : <Redirect to="/signIn" />
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {redirection}
        <Switch>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/"
            render={() => (<HomePage currentUser= 
            {this.state.currentUser} />)}
          />
          <Route exact path="/signIn" component={SignInPage} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. Your solution is kind of working beacause it's redirect me to SignInPage but after logging in i can't go back into HomePage. It still redirect me to SignInPage.

Comment: Verify if the user state is not null?

Comment: I'm checking that on the console. And user obj is on state.

Comment: Are you redirecting the user to the home page when he authenticated? verify this on your login page.

Comment: I'm not doing that yet. But i can't go back by changing the path address. And that's the point. In my theory it is happening by this way because every time when my app.js starts it is setting currentUser to null, so it is redirecing me to signIn. But i don't really know how to solve this.

Comment: When you change your path in the browser, the app lost the state, so we lost our state user, so in the component App will not find the state user and will redirect the user to login page, I edited my code to redirect the user to the login page, I changed my code to redirect the user to the home page, but this is not the perfect answer, because if the app gets re-rendered , you will redirect always to home page.

Comment: I understand your attept. I think i can solve this problem a little bit later when i change user authentication with redux..